# PHP returning all IDs from an array of parent/children given an id

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Having a problem here that maybe someone can help me with. Hours of searching couldn't find the solution so I'm at my wit's end.

I have an array,

```
$array = array(
array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Main'),
array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Something'),
array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Child of Main'),
array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Child of Child of Main'),
...
);
```

I want a function that will give me all of the ids of the parents for a given node, i.e.

```
$ids = getIDs(4);
```

would return an array of {3, 1}

Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to make structure like this?

```
 $array = array(
1=>array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Main'),
2=>array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Something'),
3=>array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Child of Main'),
4=>array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Child of Child of Main'),
...
);
```

with or without 'id' inside array

This one should works with this structure

```
function getIds($array,$x){
    if(!$array[$x]['parent_id'])
        return array();
    else
        return array_merge(array($array[$x]['parent_id']),getIds($array,$array[$x]['parent_id']));
}
```

Comment: I do it: `var_dump(getIDs($array,4));` and it doesn't work for me. I get NULL as var_dump and a warning: `array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array`.

Comment: I changed first argument of array_merge to `array($array[$x]['parent_id'])`. Then I get a notice: `Undefined offset: 15` and only one element as var_dump -- 15.

Comment: @Pawel, Oh,you are right, it was some error, edited, you can test now

Comment: @Pawel: about Undefined offset, there are should be no such error? can you show me error test?

Comment: It still doesn't work. After first execution of getIDs function `$array[$x]['parent_id']` is 15. You execute getIDs(15) but this element doesn't exist. You should execute getIDs(3) but I don't know how to correct it. Only solution I see is a loop inside getIDs function...

Comment: @Pawel: I use indexes instead of id's i don't use index 'id' at all. that's why I ask OP can he change structure. Works fine with    $array = array(
5=>array( 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Main'),
7=>array('parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Something'),
15=>array( 'parent_id' => 5, 'name' => 'Child of Main'),
23=>array( 'parent_id' => 15, 'name' => 'Child of Child of Main'),
);

Comment: See this: http://pastebin.com/8mEExMrj It's everything I get. Edit. Well, for me it doesn't work. What I do wrong (see link)?

Comment: Oh... I thought code (array) should look as in your answer (you wrote that in answer). Sorry. :) Code you wrote in answer doesn't work with that structure. Maybe correct it? :>

Answer (score 1):

I've made something similar to RiaD (but on my own). It works well with the structure you already have.

```
<?php
$array = array(
array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Main'),
array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Something'),
array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Child of Main'),
array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Child of Child of Main'),
);
$parents = array();
function getIDs($id){
    global $array, $parents;
    $tmp = $array[$id-1]['parent_id'];
    if($tmp){
        array_push($parents, $tmp);
        getIDs($tmp);
    }
}
getIDs(4);
var_dump($parents);
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you show an example when it won't work?

Comment: array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Main'),
array('id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Something'),
array('id' => 15, 'parent_id' => 5, 'name' => 'Child of Main'),
array('id' => 23, 'parent_id' => 15, 'name' => 'Child of Child of Main'), (I think id are auto-generaetd and maybe deleted)

Comment: Well, I assumed that first element in the main table has id "1", etc. If the main table won't look like in question it won't work. Then you are right.

Answer (score -1):

you can try [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)  loop or use [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)